# Getting the actual size of a view inside a container

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

Using the Storyboard editor with auto-layout and constraints, I have created a hierarchy with a UIViewController (1) inside of which there is a Container(2) into which in turn a UIViewcontroller(3) is embedded.

Setting the background color of the embedded UIViewController(3) to a different color than (1) shows me that the restraints are being enforced: Visually, it appears to have the size I expect both in the storyboard-editor, in the emulator and on my device.

But I fail to get the size of UIViewController(3) from code, I have tried accessing the UIViewControllers(3) views frame and bounds, both with incorrect results, they seem to return the same size as the size of the host UIViewController(1), which is clearly wrong since once is indeed embedded in the other.

I have tried also accessing the self.parentViewController.view frame and bounds, but these both return 0.0.

In the embedded UIViewController (3):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSLog(@"Size: %f x %f", self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    NSLog(@"Origin: %f x %f", self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y);
}
```

I would expect the output of this to be something which resembles, atleast in aspect ratio, the actual visible size of the UIViewController (3), but it is in fact equal to what I get if I put the same code from UIViewController (1), which is clearly not true since they are not of same size.

Comment: If I read correctly, a container view is retaining a view controller? That just plain doesn't sound right. [See Here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/devpedia-cocoacore/MVC.html)

Comment: John, but that is exactly what a container is for "Defines a region of a view controller that can include a view controller"

Comment: Which is why I did read incorrectly :p though I still think it breaks Cocoa's own rules. Oh well, disregard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually make an outlet for the view, which makes it much easier to get the parameters e.g. in your interface make an IBOutlet and connect to your view

```
IBOutlet UIView *outletYourView
```

and wherever you need the information call

```
outletYourView.frame.size.width;
outletYourView.frame.size.height;
```

etc.

Comment: But which view would I connect to that outlet ? The parent view?

Comment: You should connect the view you actually want to get information about e.g. UIViewController(3). Depending on if you put your IBOutlet in .h or .m you of course have to use `self.outletYourView.frame.size.width;` and `self.outletYourView.frame.size.height;`